# Enabling Developer Account to windows phone, and connect it with Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I developed my windows phone app using Visual studio 2015. It working as expected in emulator. I'm in need to check it with windows phone.Please check the screen below.. I connected the phone, it is running, but unable to connect. Please help me.
[screen shoot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy6qb.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turn data connection on in your phone and try again.